# Force on an object as gradient with respect to that vector

Tags: notation, molecular-dynamics

I'm reading an [introduction to molecular dynamics](http://cms.sjtu.edu.cn/doc/reading/md/A_Molecular_Dynamics_Primer_(Ercolessi).pdf) and I came across a particular notation for the force on the *i*th vector $\mathbf{r}_i$ as

$$\mathbf{F}_i = -\nabla_{\mathbf{r}_i}V(\mathbf{r}_1,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)$$

What does this notation mean? Does it mean

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{r}_i} = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i})?$$

And what would this be in spherical coordinates, if we represented $V$ as $V(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1,\ldots,r_N,\theta_N,\phi_N)?$

For example, if $N=2$ and $V$ depended only on the separation $|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|=r_{12}$, so that $V=f(|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|)$ for some $f(r)$, what would $\nabla_{\mathbf{r}_1} V$ and $\nabla_{\mathbf{r}_2} V$ be?

Thank you.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) has the gradient in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Do you know how to write $|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|$ in Cartesian coordinates? If so, you should be able to compute the gradient.

Comment: So would the gradient wrt a particular vector in spherical coordinates be $\nabla_{\mathbf{r}_i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r_i} \hat{\mathbf{r}}_i+\frac{1}{r_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i} \hat{\mathbf{\theta}}_i + \frac{1}{r_i \sin(\theta_i)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_i} \hat{\mathbf{\phi}}_i?$

Comment: Yes, that’s right.